# Integrating via trapezium rule in C

Tags: c, integrate

I'm trying to integrate the function `1/((1+x^2)x^0.5)` between 0 and infinity using the trapezium rule.

I need to find the value of N that gives the highest precision possible when using a double float, which I have done by running the program with increasing values of N until there is no difference between the totals given by consecutive values of N. However I am stuck in an infinite loop.

Thanks

Beth

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>

double inter(double x, double h, double y, double N, double total) 
{
        h=(y-x)/(N-1); 
        total= total +0.5*(1/((1+pow(x,2))*sqrt(x)));
        x=x+h;

    while (x<y)
        {
        total=total+(1/((1+pow(x,2))*sqrt(x)));
        x=x+h;
        //printf("t - %lf \n", total);
        //printf("x - %lf \n", x);
        }
    total= total +0.5*(1/((1+pow(x,2))*sqrt(x)));
    total=total*h;
    return total;
}

main()
{   
    double x,y,total,h,c,d,f,N, finish;
    x=DBL_EPSILON;
    y=331;
    total=0;
    N=0.5;
    c=inter(x,h,y,N,total);
    d=0;
    finish=0;

while(finish==0)
{
    d=inter(x,h,y,N,total);
    if(d==c)
    {
        finish=1;
    }
    else
    {
        c=d;
        d=0;
        h++;
        printf("%lf/n", h);
    }
}       

printf("%lf\n", d);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `h=(y-x)/(N-1)` eventually sets `h` to zero and the loop condition `x<y` never becomes false?

Comment: @Codor h could also become so small that x=x+h doesn't change x due to floating point inaccuracies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `iter()` function, `h` is negative, which causes `x` to go negative.  `sqrt()` of a negative number returns `NaN`.  Additionally, because `h` is negative, `x` continues to get smaller, thus is *always* being smaller than `y`, which is the cause of the infinite loop.

`h` is negative because the denominator (`N-1`) comes out to `-0.5` (N is passed in as 0.5).

Answer (score 0):

`double h` has not been initialised. You are passing it as a function argument, which then overwrites it to use as a local variable. However, in the main loop you increment `h` (using the `++` operator which would be better as `h+=1`) and then pass it to the function again, but it has no effect, as `h` is still over written in the function.

As a point of technique, you are using `double finish` as a boolean. It should be `int finish`.